# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException al añadir String a un arraylist

Tags: java

Tengo un ejercicio que simula a una persona comprando un viaje: el coste por noche, el billete de avión dependiendo del destino..., todo por consola.

Al principio de todo tengo un `ArrayList` que simula una base de datos de usuarios.

Tengo un bucle `while` en el `public static void main` donde pasa toda la acción.

El "cliente" introduce su nombre mediante un `scanner`, y tengo un `iterator` para  evaluar si ese nombre está dentro del `Arraylist`, si no está, lo introduce, y si está simplemente un `int` que vale 0, pasa a valer 10.

El caso es que cuando meto un nombre que no está, al intentar añadirlo con el método `add` del `ArrayList` me da el error `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException.`

Pongo el código:

```
       public class CosteViaje {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        boolean comprarViaje = true;
        int i = 0;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String usuario;
        int descuento = 0;
        ArrayList<String> usuarios = new ArrayList<String>();
        usuarios.add("admin");
        Iterator<String> it = usuarios.iterator();
        while (comprarViaje == true){

            System.out.println("introduce tu nombre porfavor");
            usuario = scanner.next();

            while(it.hasNext()){
                if (usuario.equals(it.next())){
                    System.out.println(usuario);
                descuento = 10;
                System.out.println("gracias por volver a confiar en nosotros, por ello, tienes 20€ de descuento adicional");
                }else{
                    System.out.println("dasdas"+usuario);

                    usuarios.add(usuario);
                  //el error esta aqui, 
                }

            }
            System.out.println("tu descuento es de : "+descuento);

            System.out.println("Introduzca el destino(Oviedo,Tokio,Madrid o Barcelona): ");
            String destino = scanner.next();
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println("Introduzca el número de noches: ");
            int numNoches = scanner.nextInt();



            CosteViaje costeViaje = new CosteViaje();

            int resultado1 = costeViaje.costeHotel(numNoches);
            int resultado2 = costeViaje.costeAvion(destino);
            int resultado3 = costeViaje.costeAlquilerCoche(numNoches);

            int sumaCostes = costeViaje.calculoTotal(resultado1,resultado2,resultado3,descuento);

            System.out.println("Coste total del viaje: " + sumaCostes);

            i++;
        }

    }

    public int costeHotel(int num) {

        int costeNoche = num * 140;

        return costeNoche;
    }

    public int costeAvion(String dest) {
        int vuelo = 0;
        if (dest.equals("Oviedo")) {
            vuelo = 15;
        }
        if (dest.equals("Tokio")) {
            vuelo = 700;
        }
        if (dest.equals("Barcelona") || dest.equals("Madrid")) {
            vuelo = 90;
        }
        return vuelo;
    }

    public int costeAlquilerCoche(int num) {
        int alquiler = 40;
        int costeCoche = alquiler * num;
        int costeAlquiler = 0;

        if (num >= 7) {
            costeAlquiler = costeCoche - 50;
        } else if (num >= 3) {
            costeAlquiler = costeCoche - 20;
        }
        System.out.println(costeAlquiler);
        return costeCoche;
    }

    public int calculoTotal(int a, int b, int c, int d) {

        int r = a + b + c + d;

        return r;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es verificar si el usuario ya esta en la Lista para darle es descuento deberias de cambiar tu logica así:

En vez de iterar la lista solo pregunta si el objeto ya existe dentro de la lista:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CosteViaje {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        boolean comprarViaje = true;
        int i = 0;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String usuario;
        int descuento = 0;
        List<String> usuarios = new ArrayList<String>();
        usuarios.add("admin");
        //Iterator<String> it = usuarios.iterator();
        while (comprarViaje == true) {

            System.out.println("introduce tu nombre porfavor");
            usuario = scanner.next();

            //while (it.hasNext()) {
            if (usuarios.contains(usuario)) {
                System.out.println(usuario);
                descuento = 10;
                System.out.println("gracias por volver a confiar en nosotros, por ello, tienes 20€ de descuento adicional");
            } else {
                System.out.println("dasdas" + usuario);

                usuarios.add(usuario);
                //el error esta aqui, 
            }
            //}
            System.out.println("tu descuento es de : " + descuento);

            System.out.println("Introduzca el destino(Oviedo,Tokio,Madrid o Barcelona): ");
            String destino = scanner.next();
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println("Introduzca el número de noches: ");
            int numNoches = scanner.nextInt();

            CosteViaje costeViaje = new CosteViaje();

            int resultado1 = costeViaje.costeHotel(numNoches);
            int resultado2 = costeViaje.costeAvion(destino);
            int resultado3 = costeViaje.costeAlquilerCoche(numNoches);

            int sumaCostes = costeViaje.calculoTotal(resultado1, resultado2, resultado3, descuento);

            System.out.println("Coste total del viaje: " + sumaCostes);

            i++;
        }

    }

    public int costeHotel(int num) {

        int costeNoche = num * 140;

        return costeNoche;
    }

    public int costeAvion(String dest) {
        int vuelo = 0;
        if (dest.equals("Oviedo")) {
            vuelo = 15;
        }
        if (dest.equals("Tokio")) {
            vuelo = 700;
        }
        if (dest.equals("Barcelona") || dest.equals("Madrid")) {
            vuelo = 90;
        }
        return vuelo;
    }

    public int costeAlquilerCoche(int num) {
        int alquiler = 40;
        int costeCoche = alquiler * num;
        int costeAlquiler = 0;

        if (num >= 7) {
            costeAlquiler = costeCoche - 50;
        } else if (num >= 3) {
            costeAlquiler = costeCoche - 20;
        }
        System.out.println(costeAlquiler);
        return costeCoche;
    }

    public int calculoTotal(int a, int b, int c, int d) {

        int r = a + b + c + d;

        return r;
    }
}
```

Comment: vale muchas gracias, voy a probarlo.

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciona a la perfección.

Answer (score 0):

El problema se da porque al crear un Iterator de una lista e iteras sobre él, cualquier modificación que hagas sobre la lista original hará que lance la excepción que dices.

Para hacer que funcione deberías usar la clase ListIterator, que al actuar sobre sus métodos, trabajas sobre la lista. Deberia ser algo así:

```
    List<String> usuarios = new ArrayList<>();
    usuarios.add("admin");
    ListIterator<String> it = usuarios.listIterator();
    while (comprarViaje == true){

        System.out.println("introduce tu nombre porfavor");
        usuario = scanner.next();

        while(it.hasNext()){
            if (usuario.equals(it.next())){
                System.out.println(usuario);
            descuento = 10;
            System.out.println("gracias por volver a confiar en nosotros, por ello, tienes 20€ de descuento adicional");
            }else{
                System.out.println("dasdas"+usuario);

                it.add(usuario);
              //el error esta aqui, 
            }

        }
        System.out.println("tu descuento es de : "+descuento);

        System.out.println("Introduzca el destino(Oviedo,Tokio,Madrid o Barcelona): ");
        String destino = scanner.next();
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("Introduzca el número de noches: ");
        int numNoches = scanner.nextInt();



        CosteViaje costeViaje = new CosteViaje();

        int resultado1 = costeViaje.costeHotel(numNoches);
        int resultado2 = costeViaje.costeAvion(destino);
        int resultado3 = costeViaje.costeAlquilerCoche(numNoches);

        int sumaCostes = costeViaje.calculoTotal(resultado1,resultado2,resultado3,descuento);

        System.out.println("Coste total del viaje: " + sumaCostes);

        i++;
    }
```

He probado y a mi me funciona así, espero que te sirva.

Por cierto, he cambiado el objeto de Arraylist porque normalmente se define como List. Así se me quitaban algunos warnings también.

Comment: pues no me funciona... me sigue dando el mismo error.

Comment: vale ya no me da el error, pero, no me pasa por el if en ningun momento

Comment: Has probado a debugear qué valen las variables cuando llegas a ese if?

Comment: He probado el programa y el error se subsana, que era la base de tu pregunta. Ahora bien, para hacer lo que necesitas para el ejercicio deberías cambiar tu lógica porque no es la mejor. La que ha propuesto Jialzate es una posibilidad bastante buena de hacerlo.